# Не могу понять ошибки,которою выдает valgrind

Tags: c, события, segmentation-fault, valgrind

```
int main(void) {
    // startup event system
    EventSystem_init();
    List * list = List_new();


    // add event handlers
    EventSystem_addHandler(EventHandler_new(NULL, NULL, KeyInputHandler_update));
    EventSystem_addHandler(EventHandler_new(NULL, NULL, KeyInputListener_update));
    EventSystem_addHandler(EventHandler_new(identifier, free, RoomChat_update));
    EventSystem_addHandler(EventHandler_new(list,List_free, ListHandler_update));



    // start infinite event loop
    EventSystem_loop();
    // cleanup event system
    EventSystem_cleanup();
    return 0;
}

void ListHandler_update(EventHandler * self, Event * event) {
    switch(event->type) {
        case AddToChatTypeId: {
            List * list =(List *) self->data;
            int * number = malloc(sizeof(int));
            *number = rand() % 100 ;

             List_add(self->data,number);
             printf("\nУчасник(ID %i) приєднався до чату\n", *number);
             printf("Зараз у чаті:");
             List_print(self->data);
             puts(" ");


         }break;    
         case LeftChatTypeId: {
              if(List_isEmpty(self->data)){
                    printf("\nУ чаті нікого немає\n");
               } else {
                    int* randomNumber = malloc(sizeof(int));
                    if(List_count(self->data) == 1){
                         *randomNumber = 0;
                    } else {
                         *randomNumber = rand()%(List_count(self->data) - 1);
                    }
                    printf("\n Учасник (ID %i ) покинув чат\n", *((int*)List_get(self->data, *randomNumber)));
                    List_removeAt(self->data, *randomNumber);
                    printf("Зараз у чаті:");
                    List_print(self->data);
                    puts(" ");

                    free(randomNumber);
               }
           }break;
         }
    }
```

> ```
> ==2745== Invalid read of size 8
> ==2745==    at 0x402AC9: List_free (list.c:70)
> ==2745==    by 0x4022DD: EventHandler_free (events.c:147)
> ==2745==    by 0x40260B: EventSystem_cleanup (events.c:237)
> ==2745==    by 0x401E21: main (main.c:42)
> ==2745==  Address 0x34 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
> ==2745== 
> ==2745== 
> ==2745== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
> ==2745==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x34
> ==2745==    at 0x402AC9: List_free (list.c:70)
> ==2745==    by 0x4022DD: EventHandler_free (events.c:147)
> ==2745==    by 0x40260B: EventSystem_cleanup (events.c:237)
> ==2745==    by 0x401E21: main (main.c:42)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Где-то запарывается память, в результате чего затирается значение в одном из указателей:

```
Address 0x34 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

А возможно, что к этому моменту память уже была освобождена и значение перезаписано законным путём.

Что делать: поставить точку останова на вызов `List_free`, после чего проходить код в пошаговом режиме и отслеживать значения указателей, которые там освобождаются. Как только появится что-то, что не похоже на реально выделенную память - оно. При следующем запуске под отладчиком уже целенаправленно отслеживать где именно значение этого указателя перезаписывается.

Само собой, сначала имеет смысл набросать минимальный код с заполнением списка готовыми данными, в котором эта ошибка появляется.

P.S. А что вообще за игрища с динамическим выделением памяти под `randomNumber`, `number` и т.д.?